# The use of parenthesis inside an if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am in the process of learning PHP development as a beginner i would like to ask question regarding the use of if with isset. Here the two code:

Is there any difference between these two pieces of code:

```
if ( (isset($_GET['id'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) )
```

And:

```
if (isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric($_GET['s']))
```

In the first part the `isset()` and `is_numeric()` are inside an additional set of parenthesis.

But in the second they reside inside the `if()`'s parenthesis.

Is there any difference between the first and second snippet?

Thanks in advance for any explanation and clarification.

Comment: No, there isn't. It's just encapsulating the return.

Comment: This is only useful if you want to group conditions, eg. if ( (isset($_GET['id']) || isset($_GET['something'])) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) ), otherwise it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no difference whatsoever.

The purpose of additional parenthesis (`(...)`) is to specify a particular *order of operations*, like in math. As a general rule, nothing bad will happen if you use too many parenthesis, but it can make your code a bit less clear. The two code snippets you wrote do exactly the same thing. I think the second example is cleaner.

Here's where you need them:

```
if ((conditionA || conditionB) && (conditionC || condition D)) {
   ...
}
```

They can also add clarity around mathematical expressions:

```
$x = $y * 7 + 3 / 2;

$x = ($y * 7) + (3 / 2);
```

Both of these expressions do the exact same thing, but the parenthesis make it easier to see what's going on, without remembering the order of operations.

Sometimes, you want to use a *different* order of operations, and you need them:

```
$x = $y * (7 + 3) / 2;
```

Comment: Perfectly worded there @Will!